# animate a child view of listview in position 1

Tags: android-listview, android-animation, android-adapter

I created a code that animates all the children of the ListView except the position 1.

[image]

if I reduce the application with the "home" button and I come back on, the animation of the view at position 1 is not launched. So if I press a "Preferences" button in the action bar which launches another activity, and then I press the "back" button, the animation is started.

Also, if I click on the item, the animation is started.

Finally, if I scroll to hide the view at position 1 and I scroll to draw again, the animation is started.

I do not think posting the code is useful because it works for all other views.

I tried to use the "convertView" of the Adapter, I also try to redraw the whole, it does not work.
I hope that the solution lies in an option to enable it in the ListView. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I just noticed that the view at position 1 is redrawn (in the getView method of the adapter) more times than others view.

Answer (score 0):

Your listview layout_width and layout_height attr. are match_parent? If listview layout attrs are wrap_content, it called getView every width or height changing.

Optimize adapter code but your code want position variable shouldn't use. Because very dangerous row cached.

```
    if( convertView == null){
     // inflate
     ...
     convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
     holder = ((Holder)convertView.getTag());
    }

...
```

Other options very simply but not fast and memory friendly

```
    // inflate convertView
    convertView = inflater.inflate(, );
    // than use convertViews child view
```